# QOOXDOO AJAX: Передача параметров

Tags: ajax, javascript, qooxdoo

Доброго времени суток.
Вот, познакомился с прекрасным фреймворком - qooxdoo.

Пишу...пишу и дописался до момента, когда мне нужно передать AJAX-ом некоторые параметры. Вот код этого класса:

```
qx.Class.define("myhobby.api", {
extend: qx.io.remote.Request,
members : {
    call: function(fname, obj, callback){
        this.setUrl("api.php");
        this.setMethod("POST");
        this.setData("act=" + fname);
        this.setAsynchronous(false);
        this.addListener("completed", function (e) {
            callback(e.getContent());

        });
        console.log(this.removeListener);
        this.send();
    }
}
```

});

Далее, ради интереса, я создал кнопку и повесил на нее ивент выполнения функции call этого класса. Код:

```
var button1 = new qx.ui.form.Button("First Button", "myhobby/test.png");
    var api = new myhobby.api();
    button1.addListener("execute", function(e) {
    api.call(Math.random(10000, 9999), {name: 1}, function(e){
        alert(e);
    });
});
```

Самое неприличное то, что все прекрасно отрабатвается только при первом нажатии на button. Теперь трэйс:

1. Нажимаем на кнопку, срабатывает api.call (Он срабатывает всегда)
2. Далее, попадаем в функцию call, срабатывает листенер, вызывает callback функцию и передает ей респонз.

Так вот. По второму нажатию какого-то х... черта листенер не хочет повторно отслеживать событие завершения AJAX-а. Не понимаю почему.

Если тут есть товарищи, которые работали с этим фреймворком... я был бы безумно счастлив :)) Надеюсь, на Вас :))

P.S. Копался в интернете долго, ответа не нашел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос решен через кастыль. Но работает - факт.

1. Наследовать я решил объект собственного класса "myhobby".

Получилось так:

```
qx.Class.define("myhobby.api", {
    extend: myhobby.Application, /*Вот тут я не стал наследовать "new                      qx.io.remote.Request" напрямую. Впринципе, мне это не нужно :)*/
    members : {
        call: function(fname, obj, callback) {
            var ajax = new qx.io.remote.Request("api.php", "POST");
            ajax.setData("act=" + fname);
            ajax.setAsynchronous(true);
            // this.setData(qx.util.Json.stringify(obj)); 
            ajax.addListener("completed", function (e) {
                var answer = e.getContent();
                callback(answer);
            });
            ajax.send();
        }
    }
});
```

Собственно, вот :) А вдруг кому-то помог :))

Вопрос можно считать закрытым :) Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Ключевым было вот это  ajax.setAsynchronous(true);

Comment: А вот и нет. При чем тут синхронность ?
логику я просто не включил. один реквест = один инстанс.

По этому нельзя было дважды с одного инстанса делать запрос т.к. после того как он завершается начинается его деструкт.